# Transform collection of objects to a collection of tuples

Tags: c#, tuples, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have a collection of objects. I've made sure it has an even amount of objects.

```
Object1
Object2
Object3
Object4
Object5
Object6
```

I need to transform the collection to tuples, like this

```
Tuple(Object1, Object2),
Tuple(Object3, Object4),
Tuple(Object5, Object6)
```

I've been trying to come up with an extension method for it, but I haven't figured out anything.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ToTuples(this IEnumerable<T> objects)
{
    // what do I do here?
}
```

Comment: What attempts did you make?  What about them wasn't working?

Comment: Like I said, I haven't figured out any way myself how I could achieve this. I know my way around LINQ extension methods, and I've been primarily thinking of ways using those.

Comment: @Servy, I think the OP has very clearly explained what they have tried so far on this occasion. 1. They can manually create the tuples; 2. they have explored the idea of extension methods, but don't really know how to tackle it that way.

Comment: @DavidArno He specifically said that he's been trying to create an implementation, so one would assume that if he's been trying something he wouldn't have nothing, because if that's the case then it would mean he *hasn't* in fact been trying things.  He might have nothing that works, but he wouldn't have nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
  public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ToTuples<T>(this IEnumerable<T> objects)
  {
     IEnumerator<T> enumerator = objects.GetEnumerator();
     while (enumerator.MoveNext())
     {
        T object1 = enumerator.Current;
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
           yield return Tuple.Create(object1, enumerator.Current);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: This just skips the last element if the sequence is odd-length (not specificed what behavior should be by OP), and does throw NRE if `objects == null`.

Comment: Spot on (ie this is near-identical to what I started writing and then your answer popped up). It's worth expending the answer to explain how it works though IMO.

Comment: @Mephy: You're right, I'm sure OP can tweak as necessary if he knows what he wants to do in those cases.

Comment: @Mephy I've made sure to only pass a collection of even-length. I only need this for this occasion, I'll tweak it if I need it sometime later :)